# android: listview inside a scrollView doesn't work?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I am having a `listview` inside a `scrollview`, but the problem is that the `scrollview` is scrolling but `listview` is not scrolling. I think this is due to that `scrollView`.

Can somebody who has a working solution post it here as reference?

Comment: How could your ScrollView scroll in the first place?

Comment: This not a good practice to do but if you try to give height to listview on runtime than its possible. see below link :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing/3495908#3495908

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you put your ListView/any scrollable View inside the scrollView it will not work properly because when you touch the screen ,main focus of your touch is on parent view(scrollView ) not the child View (ListView).

Answer (score 7):

Generally, you cannot put scrollable things inside other scrollable things, where they scroll in the same direction, and have the results be reliable. Occasionally this works (e.g., `WebViews` in a `ViewPager`), but that is the exception, not the norm.

Either:

- Move the `ListView` out of the `ScrollView`, or
- Move all the rest of the contents of the `ScrollView` into the `ListView`, whether using things like `addHeaderView()` or my [`MergeAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge)

Answer (score 5):

ListView must have fixed height as below in your XML file

```
        <ListView android:id="@+id/lv"
            android:listSelector="#0f0"            
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="500px" />
```

In Java file, write below code after **setContentView()**

```
        lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv);
        lv.setAdapter(your adapter here);  // you have to add your adapter here             

        lv.setOnTouchListener(new ListView.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
                {
                    lv.scrollBy(0, 1);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Make these changes to your code and test it. After too many experiments i written this code. It is working 100% fine.